# How to remove/filter out records from select * from tableName query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run a select * from tableName query, I get the following records:

```
id   Name

1    Lorum
2    Ipsum
3    Dolor
4    Sit
5    Amet
```

From these records If I use say: 'Dolor' then the query should only return the rest records with id3 like this:

```
id   Name

1    Lorum
2    Ipsum
4    Sit
5    Amet
```

I don't have access to the table, I can neither delete or update. Is there anyway to remove the records that we're using from the query and only return unused ones?

Now I how to remove one record. Like:  `select * from tableName where Name != 'Dolor'`.

Thing is there are hundreds of records I'll be GETing and I'm not sure how to do the above dynamically. I've created a table to save the records that I'll be using, so I'm here for help to know how to filter/remove the records from `select *` from query by matching them with records in that table I've created.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `select * from tableName where Name not in (select name from tempTableName)`

Comment: Or possibly (better) use an `EXISTS` so that `NULL` values are handled in a more "expected" manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not in` if there is a list of names that you don't want:

```
select *
from tableName
where Name not in ('Dolor', 'Lorem');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tableName 
where Name <> 'Dolor'
-------------------- or
select * 
from tableName 
where Name not in ('Dolor','Amet')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, you can do following:

```cs
from t in tableName
where Name != filteredName
```